# Is Mathematica matrix multiplication with its inverse wrong?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't * and ^ work as I expected on matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/574/why-dont-and-work-as-i-expected-on-matrices)

When I enter this

```
Inverse[{{-112, 49, 2, 283}, {-138, 5, 3, 359}, {-20, 0, 0, 6}, {-40, -20, 0, 12}}] *
        {{-112, 49, 2, 283}, {-138, 5, 3, 359}, {-20, 0, 0, 6}, {-40, -20, 0, 12}}
```

I don't get the identity matrix, but this output:

[image: mathematica output]

Can anybody explain why and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Dot` for matrix multiplication; `*` gives element-wise multiplication.

```
mat = {{-112, 49, 2, 283}, {-138, 5, 3, 359}, {-20, 0, 0, 6}, {-40, -20, 0, 12}} ;

Dot[mat, Inverse[mat]]

(* {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Comment: The OP's confusion might be due to the fact that [in MATLAB, `*` performs matrix multiplication, while `.*` performs Hadamard multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html). In *Mathematica*, OTOH, `*` is Hadamard multiplication, while `.` is the operator for matrix multiplication. Common trip-up...