# How to take transpose of a one dimensional vector?

Tags: matrix

Why the two followings giving me same output? At least one should give me a row vector and another should give me a column vector.

```
MatrixForm[u = {1 , 1, -1, 1}]

MatrixForm[v = {{1}, {1}, {-1}, {1}}]
```

When I am trying to get transpose of u by taking Transpose[u], I am Mathematica is showing ""The first two levels of the one-dimensional list {1,1,-1,1} cannot be transposed"". So how to take transpose of a one dimensional vector?

Comment: Mathematica's internal representation of a one-dimensional vector is the same as a (one-dimensional) list, which allows Dot[a,b] to be defined generally, even for lists that are not of numbers.  As such, the internal representation does not admit a Transpose of a one-dimensional list.  Why do you want the transpose of a one-dimensional vector (or list)?

Comment: `MatrixForm[u = {{1 , 1, -1, 1}}]` might be what you want.

Comment: @Sungmin it works. But why we do not do it using Transpose[] ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It shall be used to build up a big rank one matrix.

Comment: Can't you build up your big rank-one matrix using lists directly (i.e., without Transpose[])?  Why not post THAT problem instead?  I suspect the SE community can solve that problem for you.

Comment: The function `Transpose` permutes two (or more) distinct levels in an array/tensor. Your vector/list has only one level, so transposition is not possible. The way transposing a vector was explained to me in linear algebra was that we may consider a vector as a either a row matrix or a column matrix, which may be transposed. In *Mathematica*, a row matrix has the form `{{1 , 1, -1, 1}}`, as Sungmin points out.

Comment: I cannot resist the temptation to mention a point that I always strongly emphasized in my courses. A vector is just a list. What is called a row vector of a column vector are just two different (matrix) notations for the same vector. **A vector cannot be transposed**, but we can switch from one notation to  another by transposing the matrix notation. I am happy to see that Mathematica treats vectors in the same way.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40368/57).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  how can we fine  transpose for u = {1 , 1, -1, 1}?? thanks in advance!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM What is a ‘fine transpose’? Simple transposes are explained below or in my link above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
u = {{1, 1, -1, 1}}
(* NOT u = {1 , 1, -1, 1}, which is a list, I think *)
v = {{1}, {1}, {-1}, {1}}
MatrixForm[u]
MatrixForm[v]
```

Also

```
Transpose[u]
```