# Convert a polynomial to a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, vector

I am trying to transform a generated polynomial terms into a vector, I used the command 'MonomialList',

```
X = x - (2 x^3/a^2) + (x^4/a^3);
Y = y - (2 y^3/b^2) + (y^4/b^3);
u = (y^2 - b*y)*(2*x - a);
v = (x^2 - a*x)*(2*y - b);
w = X*Y;
L= MonomialList[u]
M= MonomialList[v]
N= MonomialList[w]
```

the result of such code was :

```
{a b y, -a y^2, -2 b x y, 2 x y^2}
{a b x, -2 a x y, -b x^2, 2 x^2 y}
{(x^4 y^4)/(a^3 b^3), -((2 x^4 y^3)/(a^3 b^2)), (
 x^4 y)/a^3, -((2 x^3 y^4)/(a^2 b^3)), (4 x^3 y^3)/(
 a^2 b^2), -((2 x^3 y)/a^2), (x y^4)/b^3, -((2 x y^3)/b^2), x y}
```

The results are so far so good, the problem is arisen when I try to treat (L,M,or N) as vectors

```
Transpose [L]
```

I receive such result :

```
Transpose[{a b y, -a y^2, -2 b x y, 2 x y^2}]
```

with error message :

```
Transpose: The first two levels of {a b y,-a y^2,-2 b x y,2 x y^2} cannot be transposed.
```

I tried to use next code to over come this problem :

```
 L = {MonomialList[u]}
```

whose result was

```
{{2. x y^2, -0.6 x y, -0.5 y^2, 0.15 y}}
```

when I tried to get the transpose[L] :

```
{{2. x y^2}, {-0.6 x y}, {-0.5 y^2}, {0.15 y}}
```

The problem is solved

Comment: [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html?q=N) is a reserved word.  You should avoid uppercase variables, as they collide with Mathematica reserved words. You should have got the error *"Set::wrsym Symbol N is protected"*. Try `l=Transpose[{MonomialList[u]}].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take transpose of a one dimensional vector?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69959/how-to-take-transpose-of-a-one-dimensional-vector)
Mathematica has no concept of row vectors and column vectors.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please stay responsive to the comments as you receive them and provide feedback so that you can be assisted further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use the next code to overcome this problem :

```
 L = {MonomialList[u]}
```

whose result was

```
{{2. x y^2, -0.6 x y, -0.5 y^2, 0.15 y}}
```

when I tried to get the `Transpose[L]` :

```
{{2. x y^2}, {-0.6 x y}, {-0.5 y^2}, {0.15 y}}
```

The problem is solved