# Why can not the vector be transposed in integrating over a region?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

```
Clear[x, A];
A = {{2, -1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1}, {0, -1, 1}};
Integrate[Exp[-x.A.{x}\[Transpose]/2], x \[Element] FullRegion[3]]
```

This code raises an error

> Transpose::nmtx: "The first two levels of {x} cannot be transposed."

How can I fix it?

Comment: For 1D lists you don't actually need to transpose but most importantly you don't want to use curly braces. Just `(x.A.x)/2` will work.

Comment: A discussion why the concept of row and column vectors are not needed can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40368/57).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
A = {{2, -1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1}, {0, -1, 1}};
Integrate[Exp[(-x . A . x)/2], x ∈ FullRegion[3]]
```

> ```
> 2 Sqrt[2] π^(3/2)
> ```