# Issue with replacement rules screwing up a matrix

Tags: replacement

I am pretty new to using Mathematica as more than a calculator. Essentially my problem is that I am trying to calculate a quantity vector quantity

$x=x_0 - A^{-1}F(x_0)$

where $x_0$ is a 3-entry column vector (of numbers), $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of a 3x3 matrix of functions of three variables, and $F$ is a column vector of three functions of the same three variables. Clearly in order to get a numerical result I need to multiply $A^{-1}$ and $F$ together and replace the three variables with numerical values.

I tried doing it like

```
x=x_0 - ((AIinv * F)/.{x_1->1, x_2->1, x_3->1})
```

where those numerical values for the variables are just some that I made up just now. The thing is that when I apply the replacement rules the term (AInv * F) loses its matrix form and turns into a "multidimensional array", which prevents me from subtracting it from $x_0$. In order to fix it I have tried applying MatrixForm[] and Flatten[] and the two in combination to the (AInv*F) term but it does not help. It seems like this would all work great if this wasn't happening. I would appreciate anybody's help!!
Thanks much

Comment: x_0 gives (*0*). Consider renaming it as x0.

Comment: it's actually x{sub}0 with the build in typesetting (on my mac it's control hyphen)

Comment: The proper syntax is Subscript[x, 0], but still try renaming all as x1, x2 etc.

Comment: It might be easier for us to help if you copy the definitions of `F` and `A1inv` into your post. In addition, while `x_0` can be interpreted as `Subscript[x,0]`, it's better if you post code in completely correct *Mathematica* code format, so that potential answerers on this site can copy and paste your code into their own copies of *Mathematica*, facilitating quick answers.

Comment: You will want to have a close look at documentation for `Dot` (used e.g. for matrix-times-vector) and also `MatrixForm`. That latter is a wrapper for formatting and will change the `Head` from `List` to `MatrixForm`, which will make further computation difficult.

Comment: Many new users of Mathematica seem to be confused about using column and row vectors, probably because of having used Matlab. Check [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40368/57) for a description of the Mathematica way.

Comment: BTW a matrix *is* a multidimensional array. Apparently you have been working with MatrixForm which is meant for the *display* of such a matrix only. If you do res=MatrixForm[matrix expression] the result will look like a nice matrix but it is actually a matrix with an invisible wrapper around it. This wrapper will now stick around because of the assignment and will cause problems further on.

Answer (score 1):

I made up matrices for demonstration. You should use your own.

```
A = x1 x2 x3 RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
f = RandomReal[1, 3];
func [x0_] = x0 - LinearSolve[A, f] /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1};

MatrixForm@func[1]
```

*Edited after J.M. pointed out that I omitted a dot.*

Comment: This helped me greatly. Also I changed the formatting from the graphical matrices made using the palette to ones of the form {{}{}{}}. Everything is working now, thanks!

Comment: That should probably be `Inverse[A].f`, but in practice, `LinearSolve[A, f]` is the preferred route.