# Solve an ODE using matrices

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I have the following system:
$m\cdot\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=-k(x-lo)-\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot d+m\cdot g$
It represents a mass with a spring and a damper. It is easy to solve using NDSolve but I'm trying to solve it using matrices. (Because if we represent the system using state equations, we can use some transformations, like diagonalization or triangularization so the time of computation is reduced). I tried using regular matrices but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?
The system after an order reduction is:

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x1'(t) \\
    x2'(t) \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    \frac{-k}{m} & \frac{-d}{m} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x1 \\
    x2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}+
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    \frac{1}{m}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    f(t)
    +
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    \frac{kl_o}{m}+g\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    $

where $f(t)=15u(t-5)$ (u(t) is the unit step function).

I have tried this:

```
lo = 0.50; m = 1.5; k = 20; d = 3; g = 9.8;
A = {{0, 1}, {-k/m, -m}}  
z[t_] = 15*HeavisideTheta[t - 5];
b = {{0}, {1/m}};
γ = {{0}, {(k*lo)/m + g}};
S = A*{{x0[t]}, {x1[t]}} + b*z[t] + γ 
eqns = {{x0'[t]}, {x1'[t]}} 
NDSolve[{eqns == A*{{x0[t]}, {x1[t]}} + b*z[t] + γ , 
  x0[0] == 0, x1[0] == 0}, {x0[t], x1[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: As a tip: `HeavisideTheta[]` is intended for *symbolic* use only; for numerics, like in your situation, please use `UnitStep[]`. Also, matrix-vector multiplication is `.` (`Dot[]`), not `*` (`Times[]`).

Comment: What values do `k`, `m`, `lo`, `g` have?

Comment: Thanks! Now it works better. I tried to solve the system with f(t)=0 and I got the correct solution using your tips. But I still can't get the solution using f(t). (Mathematica says "non-numerical value at t==0" )

Comment: lo = 0.50;
m = 1.5;
k = 20;
d = 3;
g = 9.8;

Comment: Please include such constants in your questions the next time instead of making other people ask for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code runs with a few minor modifications, as suggested by J.M.  In addition, `A` was corrected, and constants given numerical values.  Then,

```
k = 1; lo = 1; m = 1; d = 1; g = 1;
A = {{0, 1}, {-k/m, -d/m}};
z[t_] = 15*UnitStep[t - 5];
b = {{0}, {1/m}};
γ = {{0}, {(k*lo)/m + g}};
eqns = {{x0'[t]}, {x1'[t]}};
s = Flatten@NDSolve[{eqns == A.{{x0[t]}, {x1[t]}} + b z[t] + γ, 
    x0[0] == 0, x1[0] == 0}, {x0[t], x1[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: I know the basic use of Flatten, but you used here to solve the system. Why does it work with Flatten, but it didn't work using regular matrix operations? I mean, why is it necessary to use Flatten?

Comment: @MiguelDuranDiaz  `Flatten` is used only to remove an extra set of `{ }` from `s` for plotting purposes.  It has nothing to do with obtaining a solution.

Comment: @Miguel, if you'd used vectors instead of column matrices, then the `Flatten[]` would not have been necessary, as Carl notes: `With[{lo = 0.50, m = 1.5, k = 20, d = 3, g = 9.8}, NDSolveValue[{{x0'[t], x1'[t]} == {{0, 1}, {-k/m, -d/m}}.{x0[t], x1[t]} + {0, 1/m} (15 UnitStep[t - 5]) + {0, k lo/m + g}, x0[0] == 0, x1[0] == 0}, {x0, x1}, {t, 0, 10}]]`. Please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40366).

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid column matrices:

```
A = {{0,1},{-k/m,-d/m}};
z[t_]:={0, 15UnitStep[t-5]}
lo = 0.50; 
m = 1.5; 
k = 20; 
d = 3; 
g = 9.8;
b = {0,1/m};
γ = {0,(k lo)/m+g};
```

Then, you can use the vector form of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve)/[`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) as follows:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {x'[t] == A . x[t] + b z[t] + γ, x[0] == {0,0}},
    x,
    {t,0,10}
]
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>]

Finally, a plot:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]