# Matrix Multiplication gives a wrong answer

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to multiply a matrix 4x1 with a vector 1x4. I'm supposed to get a matrix 4x4. When I try to multiply both matrices I get an error, incompatible shapes. It doesn't make any sense because the shapes are compatible so probablyh I'm doing something wrong:

```
B = {{3619.3}, {3619.3}, {-29800}, {0}} 
Cc = {0, 0, 0, 1} 
B.Cc
```

> Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{3619.3},{3619.3},{-29800},{0}} and {0,0,0,1}
>   have incompatible shapes.

I tried doing similar multiplications but sometimes Matheamtica doesn't give any error but gives me wrong a answer which is worse. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want `Outer[Times, {3619.3, 3619.3, -29800, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: Have a look at the this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VectorsAndMatrices.html) and related ones. The error message you get is very explicit about what went wrong.

Comment: Outer works. As far as I know, outer matchs the usual matrix multiplication when multiplying m x 1 * n x 1 vectors. Am I supposed to always use "outer" when I want to do that? How do I know that mathematica returns a correct result with general matrices A={mxn}, B={nxp} when I try to do "A.B" ?

Comment: You could do `B . {Cc}` instead.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40368).

Comment: TIL:  As explained in [the answer JM links](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40368), one might also do `{{3619.3}, {3619.3}, {-29800}, {0}}.{{0, 0, 0, 1}}`, which you might find more satisfying.  Essentially to force Mathematica to think of it as a row vector, you have to make it a 1xn matrix.  (**Edit** I now realize Carl Woll also said something similar above.)