# How to check if a vector is an eigenvector of a matrix using mathematica?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, expression-test, eigenvalues

Here is a vector

$$\begin{pmatrix}i\\7i\\-2\end{pmatrix}$$

Here is a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}2& i&0\\-i&1&1\\0 &1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Is there a simple way to determine whether the vector is an eigenvector of this matrix?

Here is some code for your convenience.

```
h = {{2, I, 0 },
     {-I, 1, 1},
     {0, 1, 0}};

y = {I, 7 I, -2};
```

Comment: Could also do `h.y/y`. Dividing by `y` divides element-wise, and so if it's an eigenvector, each element of the resulting vector should be the same (which is the eigenvalue).

Comment: @march: Division by zero (not in this case, but in general)...?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. Sure, it's not completely general, which is partly why I didn't write it as an answer.

Comment: @march It's still a good idea.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. It's straight-forward, anyway.

Comment: Solve the eigenvalue/vector equation: `Solve[h.y == lambda*y, lambda]`. It is an eigenvector iff solution set is nonempty.

Comment: Could use `Eigenvectors[h]` and compare

Comment: Would be interesting to generalise your question to large symbolic matrices.

Answer (score 37):

You could use [`MatrixRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixRank). Here is a function that does this:

```
eigenvectorQ[matrix_, vector_] := MatrixRank[{matrix . vector, vector}] == 1
```

For your example:

```
eigenvectorQ[h, y]
```

> False

Comment: Slick... (and an upvote)

Comment: That is the right way

Answer (score 8):

For problems with exact coordinates, one could code up the definition of eigenvector.  The function `eigV` finds the eigenvalue for a given vector in the form `L == value` or returns `False` if there is none;  the function `eigQ` returns `True` if there exists an eigenvalue for

```
ClearAll[eigQ, eigV];
eigV[m_, v_] := Reduce@Thread[(m - SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> L, Dimensions[m]]).v == 0];
eigV[m_][v_] := eigV[m, v]; (* operator form *)
eigQ[m_, v_] := Resolve@Exists[L, eigV[m, v]];
eigQ[m_][v_] := eigQ[m, v]; (* operator form *)
```

Examples:

```
eigQ[h] /@ {y, {-I (-2 + Sqrt[3]), 1 - Sqrt[3], 1}}
(*  {False, True}  *)

eigV[h] /@ {y, {-I (-2 + Sqrt[3]), 1 - Sqrt[3], 1}}
(*  {False, L == 1 - Sqrt[3]}  *)
```

Or simply

```
eigQ[h, y]
(*  False  *)
```

For approximate problems, one would have to account for rounding error.

Comment: Note: It's simpler to use Daniel Lichtblau's form for the equation: `eigV[m_, v_] := Reduce[m.v == L*v]`  (brain spasm sent me on the roundabout way, I guess).

Comment: Why not just `Resolve@Exists[α, #1.#2 == α #2] & @@ {h, y}`?

Comment: @aardvark2012 Fair enough. I had something like that at one point.  But I was enamored with `eigV`; for some reason, it appealed to me.  Maybe the eigenvalue as a certificate of proof, I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! We just check whether $h.y = (u + I v) y$ holds for some real $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$.

```
h = {{2, I, 0}, {-I, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
y = {I, 7 I, -2};
expr = Norm[h.y - (u + I v) y, 2]^2 // ComplexExpand;
Minimize[expr, {u, v}]
```

> {623/6, {u -> 17/18, v -> 0}}

Answer: Nope, it's not.

Answer (score 5):

You already have several good answers. An alternative is to use a [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient),

```
r = First[y.h.ConjugateTranspose[{y}]/Norm[y]];
```

The vector `y` is an eigenvector of `h` if and only if the matrix
$$
h-r1_{3\times3}
$$
is singular:

```
MatrixRank[h - IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] R]<Length[y]
(*False*)
```

or

```
Det[h - IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] R] == 0
(*False*)
```

If you are using floating point numbers, you should change this condition into

```
MatrixRank[h - IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] R,Tolerance->epsilon]<Length[y]
```

or

```
Abs[Det[h - IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] R]] < epsilon
```

where `epsilon` is some small number.

As a matter of fact, the `MatrixRank` method is slightly faster than the `Det` one. It seems to me that it is also faster than the methods suggested by other users, but confirming this would require a more thorough analysis.

Comment: For full masochistic effect you should have him calculate the determinant by cofactor expansion. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
Reduce[h . y == x * y, x]
```

or

```
Reduce[(h - IdentityMatrix[Length[h]] x) . y == 0, x]
```

depending on whether you would rather type $y$ once or twice.

Answer (score 3):

Carl Woll's answer seems to be broken in the newest Mathematica. Here is a slight modification that makes it work

```
EigenvectorQ[matrix_, vector_] := MatrixRank[Join[matrix.vector, vector, 2]] == 1
```

`MatrixRank` gives the number of linearly dependent columns.
`Join[l1, l2, 2]` joins the second vector to the first on the right.

Comment: If you think about it, the rank of a matrix ought to be the same whether transposed or not. Can you give an example of a matrix-vector pair where Carl's version fails, but yours works?

Comment: @J.M. For whatever reason, I had trouble with it a week ago, but not today. Even with the same matrices. I'll delete this post in a bit.

Comment: @J.M., Actually, with some more experimenting (and more Diffeq homework), Carl Woll's answer doesn't work for the matrix {{4, 5},{-2, 6}} with the eigenvector{{1 - 3:ii:},{2}}. It doesn't seem to work with any vector with complex eigenvectors

Comment: `With[{m = {{4, 5}, {-2, 6}}, v = {1 - 3 I, 2}}, MatrixRank[{m.v, v}] == 1]` gives `True`. Also, why are you inputting eigenvectors in a format like `{{1 - 3 I}, {2}}`? Have you already seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40368)?

Comment: I'm using ctr+Enter and ctr+, to make a matrix within Mathematica, and passing the values that way. I haven't seen the link you sent, thank you for the info.

Comment: Yes, that's good for matrices, but don't use that for vectors.

Answer (score 2):

```
MemberQ[myeigens = Normalize/@Eigenvectors[h], Normalize[y]]|| MemberQ[myeigens, -Normalize[y]]
```

(* False *)

Comment: And what if you have eigenvalues with multiplicities?

Comment: Won't you find the match in that case?

Comment: Not necessarily. The eigenspace to an eigenvalue with higher multiplicity may have dimension greater than 1 and `Eigenvectors` just picks a basis. So, it will likely happen that neither `Normalize[y]` nor `-Normalize[y]` coincides with one of the basis vectors.

Comment: Here, a counter example: `MemberQ[Eigenvectors[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]], 
 Normalize[{1, -1}] || -Normalize[{1, -1}]]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher:  But the eigenvectors of `DiagonalMatrix[{1,1}]` are `{1,0}` and `{0,1}`, so of course your code will yield `False`.

Comment: Every nonzero vector is an eigenvector for the identity matrix, so it should yield `True`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher:  Ah... good point.  Well, isn't that a special case, though?  Do we need to address such a degenerate case?

Comment: Well, you are right: The set of matrices for which this applies is a null set. However, math homework matrices tend to be rather artificial, you know ;o)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
eigenVectorQ[mat_, vec_] := Abs[Dot[#1\[Conjugate], #2]] == Norm[#1] Norm[#2] &[mat.vec, vec]
```

Then `eigenVectorQ[h, y]` returns `False`.