# Hessian matrix product in Taylor expansion of vector function

Tags: matrix, series-expansion, vector-calculus

I am trying to get the 2nd order coefficient of the Taylor expansion at $\pmb{x}=\pmb{0}$ of

```
f[{x1_, x2_}] = {{c1 x1^2 + c2 x1 x2 + c3 x2^2}, {d1 x1^2 + d2 x1 x2 + d3 x2^2}}
```

[image]

so, taking [these notes](https://mathinsight.org/taylors_theorem_multivariable_introduction) into account, I calculated the Hessian matrix,

```
x1 /: Dt[x1, x2] = 0;
x2 /: Dt[x2, x1] = 0;

H = Dt[f[{x1, x2}], {{x1, x2}, 2},Constants -> {c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3}]
(* {{{{2*c1, c2}, {c2, 2*c3}}}, {{{2*d1, d2}, {d2, 2*d3}}}} *)
```

[image]

and, as described in the notes, multiplied it by $\pmb{x^T}$ on the left and $\pmb{x}$ on the right

```
X = {{x1}, {x2}}

Expand[X\[Transpose].H.X]
(* {{{{2*c1*x1^2 + c2*x2*x1 + 2*d1*x2*x1 + d2*x2^2}, {c2*x1^2 + 2*c3*x2*x1 + d2*x2*x1 + 2*d3*x2^2}}}} *)
```

[image]

but the result is not as expected, as it should be equal to $\pmb{f}$ (ignoring the 1/2 factor).

**I think I followed [Mathematica's matrix/vector product rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40366/matrix-multiplication-in-context-of-row-and-column-vectors), so what am I missing?**

**Note: I am aware there are other simpler solutions such as**

```
Normal[Series[f[{(x1 - 0) t, (x2 - 0) t}], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1
(* {c1 x1^2+c2 x1 x2+c3 x2^2,d1 x1^2+d2 x1 x2+d3 x2^2} *)
```

**but I still want to know what I might have done wrong.**

Comment: Related: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html#3995400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `f` is vector-values, you should better multiply from the right:

```
f[{x1_, x2_}] = {{c1 x1^2 + c2 x1 x2 + c3 x2^2}, {d1 x1^2 + d2 x1 x2 + d3 x2^2}};
H = D[f[{x1, x2}], {{x1, x2}, 2}];
X = {x1, x2};
f[X] == 1/2 (H.X).X // Expand
```

> True

Comment: Seriously? I tried quite a few possibilities with f and x written as {{a},{b}} or {a,b} because of the issue with vectors in the link I posted, but missed that one. Oh well... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One problem (or difference from the notes) is that your function `f[]` is matrix-valued instead of scalar-valued. Your `H` turns out to be a matrix of Hessian matrices.  Your method of computing the Hessian turns out to replace each scalar component of `f[{x1, x2}]` by its Hessian matrix.  To recover `f[]`, you need to apply `Dot[]` at the appropriate level.

Another difference is that `X` is a matrix (depth-2 array) instead of a vector (depth-1 array). While there is a natural isomorphism from $(2\times1)$-matrices to $2$-vectors, programmatically it makes a difference, since `X\[Transpose].mat.X` results in a $1\times1$ matrix `{{q}}` instead of a scalar `q`.

So `H` turns out to be a $2 \times 1$ matrix whose entries are $2 \times 2$ matrices.

```
Dimensions[H]
(*  {2, 1, 2, 2}  *)
```

The entries are the Hessian matrices `h` of the corresponding scalar entry of `f[]`.

Addressing the first point, we can apply `X\[Transpose].h.X/2` to each Hessian component matrix `h` by using `Map`.  The entries `h` of the matrix `H` are at level 2.  The following then gets the `Dot[]` product right:

```
Map[Expand[X\[Transpose].#.X/2] &, H, {2}]
(*  {{{{c1 x1^2 + c2 x1 x2 + c3 x2^2}}}, {{{d1 x1^2 + d2 x1 x2 + d3 x2^2}}}}  *)
```

The following breaks down the computation and illustrates the parts, which can get lost in the braces; `pr[]` prints each `Dot[]` result and highlights them in red:

```
pr[result_] := (Print["res -> ", result, ", dim -> ", 
    Dimensions[result]]; Style[result, Red]);
Map[pr@Expand[X\[Transpose].#.X/2] &, H, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above shows that output as a $2 \times 1$ matrix with $1 \times 1$ matrix entries.

That's why the OP's code wasn't working. The principal problem is making `X` a matrix instead of a vector.  One might wonder whether the function `f[]` should be matrix- or vector-valued, since most vectors in the question appear as column matrices; but both types of functions are valid.  If we use a vector, `Dot[]` contracts the last level of the tensor `H`:

```
X2 = {x1, x2};
H.X2 // Dimensions
H.X2.X2 // Dimensions
(*
  {2, 1, 2}
  {2, 1}
*)
```

The product `H.X2.X2/2` is practically equivalent to use of `Map` at level `{2}`, but has the desired dimensions and is equal to `f[X2]`. This is the solution that [@Henrik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) shows in his answer.